# Okhttp Unable to connect to a localhost endpoint throws Connected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: python, android, kotlin, flask, okhttp

I am trying to connect my local backend and front end together using okhttp and flask, however i am getting java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 5000) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) exception

Now that API does work correctly as i can reach it in postman where it returns values, here is the code

```
from flask import request, Flask
import getMovie
import getUser

api = Flask(__name__)

#Movie Endpoints

@api.route('/Movies/GetMovieById', methods=['GET'])
def get_movie_by_id():
    id = str(request.args['id'])
    return getMovie.getById(id)


@api.route('/Movies/All', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_movies():
    return getMovie.getAll()

#User Endpoints

@api.route('/Users/All', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_users():
    return getUser.getAll()

@api.route('/Users/GetUserById', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_by_id():
    id = str(request.args['id'])
    return getUser.getById(id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run()
```

Then here is the mainactivity for the android app

```
package com.example.moviebuffs

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.moviebuffs.ui.main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.main_activity.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var movieListAdapter: MovieListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        movieListAdapter= MovieListAdapter(mutableListOf())

        rvFilmList.adapter = movieListAdapter
        rvFilmList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)


        var testMovie = Movie(1,"Jurassic Park","Action | Dinosaurs")

        for (i in 1..100) {
            movieListAdapter.addMovie(testMovie)
        }

        fetchTest()

    }

    fun fetchTest() {
        print("Trying to connect....")

        val url: HttpUrl = HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .host("127.0.0.1")
            .port(5000)
            .addPathSegment("Movies")
            .addPathSegment("All")
            .build()


        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response?.body?.string()
                print(body)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
               val x = 0
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    fun toGenreActivity(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        val intent = Intent(this, GenreActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    }

    fun toUserActivity(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        val intent = Intent(this, UserActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    }

    fun toMovieActivity(v: View?) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MovieActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

And here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.moviebuffs">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ui.main.GenreActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ui.main.MovieActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ui.main.UserActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you running flask app on android or pc?

Comment: running it on pc windows

Comment: and the android app on emulator or android?

Comment: running it on an emulator

Comment: I do not know what is happening, but I am sure that the emulator is unable to access the server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Localhost loopback address 127.0.0.1 refers to the device itself. You don't have the server running on your Android emulator.

Use 10.0.2.2 instead to connect to the host where the emulator is running on.

More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking